# Длинная арифметика и основание 2^32

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Хочется хранить большие числа в системе счисления по основанию `2^32` для увеличения скорости работы и уменьшения объема необходимой памяти. Вопрос в том, как преобразовывать это всё в десятичную систему для ввода-вывода?

Для преобразования из двоичной нашелся [double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble). Для преобразования из десятичной пока нашелся лишь reversed double dabble, реализованный в minecraft. И эта ситуация наводит меня на мысль, что я делаю что-то не так.

В итоге вопрос: как оптимально хранить длинные числа (правильно ли я хочу использовать систему счисления по основанию `2^32`) и как оптимально переводить запись в десятичную и из нее?

*Пояснение:* задание отчасти «учебное» — для себя. Так что вариант «выбросить велосипед» не принимается. Вариант использовать основание 10^9 хорош, но я приберегу его для олимпиад: если бы я делал что-то серьезное, конечно использовал бы GMP или boost.

Comment: Простой метод — уметь делить число на 10 с остатком. Последовательным делением вы будете находить десятичные цифры, начиная с конца.

Comment: Для ввода надо, наоборот, в цикле умножать ваше «длинное число» на 10, и прибавлять к нему цифру.

Comment: А вам серьёзно нужно именно **основание** 2^32? Что вы будете использовать в качестве цифр, которых вам понадобится 42949467296 штук?

Comment: @NickVolynkin с основанием тут все как раз понятно - автор фактически повторяет идею из GNU MP - число хранится как значение в системе счисления по основанию 2^(2^n), в зависимости от архитектуры. Количество "Разрядов" определяется динамически или статически. Понятно, что для ввода и вывода эти числа конвертируются в десятичную систему. GNU MP оптимизирована дальше некуда (длинные куски на ассемблере), так что пытаться с ней тягаться можно только при наличии неограниченных резервов по свободному времени.

Comment: @NickVolynkin в качестве цифр он будет использовать 32х-разрядные целые числа. Сверхбольшие основания - это нормальная практика для длинной арифметики, здорово сокращает время выполнения алгоритмов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: ого, не знал. Ну да, преобразование между системами счисления с основаниями 2 и 2^32 производится элементарно. Пойду, почитаю что-нибудь про это.

Comment: @Zelta Можете попробовать хранить степени 10 вплоть до самого длинного своего числа. Перевод происходит вычитанием максимальной подходящей степени и выставлением соотв. разрядов десятичного числа как 1*кол-во-вычитаний. Обратите внимание, двоичная запись степеней двойки удлиняется на 3-4 двоичных разряда на ступень и при этом с конца появляется примерно на один 0 больше. Т.е. у 10^20 младшие 19 бит пустые. Таким образом будет разумно хранить все значащие старшие 2^32 разряды, разрядность в основании 2^32 и длину не значащего хвоста, что бы останавливать вычитание досрочно, когда далее только 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно как проще - используйте лучше основание 10^9, на олимпиадах я всегда именно его и использовал.

А если хочется максимально эффективно записывать числа - то "школьный" алгоритм преобразования системы счисления делением в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Выбросить велосипед. Маловероятно, что вы сделаете что-то лучше, чем [The GNU
Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/).